# When I compile tex in vscode by tex workshop, I lose focus from my editor?

Tags: mactex, visual-studio-code

I reinstall my MacOS last week. I can save my tex code and then vscode will show the PDF of tex in the right by vscode tab, and I can just go ahead and change the code without modifying the cursor position. After reinstall MacOS and set the same config, once in a while I save tex code, it lose focus from editor and focus on the PDF. It troubled me a lot.
This is my vscode settings.json file text:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "editor.fontLigatures": null,

    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
          "before": ["j", "j"],
          "after": ["<Esc>"]
        }
    ],
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/chant/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/chant/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,

    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
      {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "command": "xelatex",
        "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "%DOC%"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "%DOC%"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "%DOC%"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
          "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
      }
    ],

    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
      {
        "name": "XeLaTeX",
        "tools": [
          "xelatex"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "PDFLaTeX",
        "tools": [
          "pdflatex"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "tools": [
          "latexmk"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "BibTeX",
        "tools": [
          "bibtex"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "xelatex -> bibtex -> xelatex*2",
        "tools": [
          "xelatex",
          "bibtex",
          "xelatex",
          "xelatex"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2",
        "tools": [
          "pdflatex",
          "bibtex",
          "pdflatex",
          "pdflatex"
        ]
      },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave",
    "latex-workshop.latex.rootFile.useSubFile": false

}
```

Comment: I run into the same issue as you lately, the line: ```
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
``` does not work the same way as in previous versions. Just try deleting this config.